Can't get the required simulation waveform of a quasi-z source inverter using Si MOSFET
This is the circuit I'm trying to replicate, with the waveform:


I found it here.
This is my attempt at it, but the waveform does not match:

Update:
This is the waveform I got. How do I get it without any distortion?



"they do not match": How do they differ? show us your waveform, please, so we can help you! Explain what you investigated yet, so that we don't tell you to do things you've already done :)

I've figured that the value to generate triangle(tri), sine (sine_90 and sine_180) are missing. What will be the value to get the required waveform.

sine and sine_180 seem easy enough as long as you know the frequency.  The 2nd one should be the same as the first except with 180 set for Phi[deg].  Triangle waves can also be done in LTspice too. Try playing around with the values until you can reverse engineer the values required to generate the waveforms in the paper.

The waveforms match quite well. There is no "distortion" of any kind. The waveforms were cleaned up for publication - those vertical white lines would have been a distraction. The filled areas in the paper mean "here the thing is switching furiously" :)
